# нужно написать адресс для нахождения district в массиве json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

в массиве json есть distict и соответствующее значение, и мне нужно получить не значение, а полный адрес, вбив который можно получить искомый district

```
{
  "response": {
    "GeoObjectCollection": {
      "metaDataProperty": {
        "GeocoderResponseMetaData": {
          "request": "ул. Псковская",
          "results": "10",
          "found": "73"
        }
      },
      "featureMember": [
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Москва, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Москва, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Центральный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Москва"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Москва"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Москва, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Москва",
                      "Locality": {
                        "LocalityName": "Москва",
                        "Thoroughfare": {
                          "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Москва, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "37.549678 55.897841",
                "upperCorner": "37.55708 55.905982"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "37.552912 55.900986"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Санкт-Петербург, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Санкт-Петербург, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Северо-Западный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Санкт-Петербург"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Санкт-Петербург"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Санкт-Петербург, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Санкт-Петербург",
                      "Locality": {
                        "LocalityName": "Санкт-Петербург",
                        "Thoroughfare": {
                          "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Санкт-Петербург, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "30.276989 59.918084",
                "upperCorner": "30.284382 59.921173"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "30.280681 59.919635"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Новгородская область, Великий Новгород, Псковский район, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Новгородская область, Великий Новгород, Псковский район, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Северо-Западный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Новгородская область"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "area",
                      "name": "городской округ Великий Новгород"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Великий Новгород"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "district",
                      "name": "Псковский район"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Новгородская область, Великий Новгород, Псковский район, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Новгородская область",
                      "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                        "SubAdministrativeAreaName": "городской округ Великий Новгород",
                        "Locality": {
                          "LocalityName": "Великий Новгород",
                          "DependentLocality": {
                            "DependentLocalityName": "Псковский район",
                            "Thoroughfare": {
                              "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Псковский район, Великий Новгород, Новгородская область, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "31.221586 58.501981",
                "upperCorner": "31.259773 58.523858"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "31.24063 58.513001"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Вологда, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Вологда, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Северо-Западный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Вологодская область"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "area",
                      "name": "городской округ Вологда"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Вологда"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Вологда, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Вологодская область",
                      "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                        "SubAdministrativeAreaName": "городской округ Вологда",
                        "Locality": {
                          "LocalityName": "Вологда",
                          "Thoroughfare": {
                            "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Вологда, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "39.82953 59.191684",
                "upperCorner": "39.857566 59.201735"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "39.841091 59.196325"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Тверь, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Тверь, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Центральный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Тверская область"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "area",
                      "name": "городской округ Тверь"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Тверь"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Тверь, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Тверская область",
                      "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                        "SubAdministrativeAreaName": "городской округ Тверь",
                        "Locality": {
                          "LocalityName": "Тверь",
                          "Thoroughfare": {
                            "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Тверь, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "35.875937 56.805008",
                "upperCorner": "35.918589 56.821434"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "35.896885 56.813306"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Киргизия, Бишкек, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "KG",
                  "formatted": "Киргизия, Бишкек, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Киргизия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "город республиканского подчинения Бишкек"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Бишкек"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Киргизия, Бишкек, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "KG",
                    "CountryName": "Киргизия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "город республиканского подчинения Бишкек",
                      "Locality": {
                        "LocalityName": "Бишкек",
                        "Thoroughfare": {
                          "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Бишкек, Киргизия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "74.568658 42.846952",
                "upperCorner": "74.568837 42.85413"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "74.568783 42.850541"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Беларусь, Минск, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "BY",
                  "formatted": "Беларусь, Минск, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Беларусь"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Минск"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Минск"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Беларусь, Минск, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "BY",
                    "CountryName": "Беларусь",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Минск",
                      "Locality": {
                        "LocalityName": "Минск",
                        "Thoroughfare": {
                          "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Минск, Беларусь",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "27.619817 53.935474",
                "upperCorner": "27.623366 53.9377"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "27.621614 53.93655"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Псковская область, Порхов, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Псковская область, Порхов, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Северо-Западный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Псковская область"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "area",
                      "name": "Порховский район"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Порхов"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Псковская область, Порхов, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Псковская область",
                      "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                        "SubAdministrativeAreaName": "Порховский район",
                        "Locality": {
                          "LocalityName": "Порхов",
                          "Thoroughfare": {
                            "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Порхов, Псковская область, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "29.528378 57.756419",
                "upperCorner": "29.56016 57.763098"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "29.543703 57.760045"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Украина, Киев, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "UA",
                  "formatted": "Украина, Киев, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Украина"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Киев"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Киев"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Украина, Киев, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "UA",
                    "CountryName": "Украина",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Киев",
                      "Locality": {
                        "LocalityName": "Киев",
                        "Thoroughfare": {
                          "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Киев, Украина",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "30.506643 50.412473",
                "upperCorner": "30.509823 50.413816"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "30.508206 50.413214"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "GeoObject": {
            "metaDataProperty": {
              "GeocoderMetaData": {
                "precision": "street",
                "text": "Россия, Новгородская область, Солецкое городское поселение, Сольцы, Псковская улица",
                "kind": "street",
                "Address": {
                  "country_code": "RU",
                  "formatted": "Россия, Новгородская область, Солецкое городское поселение, Сольцы, Псковская улица",
                  "Components": [
                    {
                      "kind": "country",
                      "name": "Россия"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Северо-Западный федеральный округ"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "province",
                      "name": "Новгородская область"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "area",
                      "name": "Солецкий район"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "area",
                      "name": "Солецкое городское поселение"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "locality",
                      "name": "Сольцы"
                    },
                    {
                      "kind": "street",
                      "name": "Псковская улица"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "AddressDetails": {
                  "Country": {
                    "AddressLine": "Россия, Новгородская область, Солецкое городское поселение, Сольцы, Псковская улица",
                    "CountryNameCode": "RU",
                    "CountryName": "Россия",
                    "AdministrativeArea": {
                      "AdministrativeAreaName": "Новгородская область",
                      "SubAdministrativeArea": {
                        "SubAdministrativeAreaName": "Солецкий район",
                        "Locality": {
                          "LocalityName": "Сольцы",
                          "Thoroughfare": {
                            "ThoroughfareName": "Псковская улица"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "name": "Псковская улица",
            "description": "Сольцы, Солецкое городское поселение, Новгородская область, Россия",
            "boundedBy": {
              "Envelope": {
                "lowerCorner": "30.283807 58.110703",
                "upperCorner": "30.303283 58.112804"
              }
            },
            "Point": {
              "pos": "30.293509 58.111987"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ну во-первых это не JSON, в JSON все-таки все ключи и стринговые квотируются  двойными кавычками `"..."`, а не одинарными.
Во-вторых, можете пояснить подробнее (желательно с примером и ождаемым результатом), что все-таки необходимо сделать? - из вопроса это не совсем понятно

Comment: вот одна из строк в коде питона, с похожей целью, тут вопросов не возникло           toponym = json_response["response"]["GeoObjectCollection"][
    "featureMember"][0]["GeoObject"]

Comment: Если речь идет о питоне, то пишется рекурсивный поиск по джейсону попутно составляя путь к искомому значению. Если из коммандной строки - то задачка решается тривиально - есть такие утилитки как **_jq_**, **`jtc`**